# Servlet to servlet connection across servers

Tags: java, servlets

We have a Servlet/JSP based application running on Websphere application server running on AIX server. There is another Tomcat server (on a different machine) between the client and previously mentioned application on Websphere server.  How can i make a connection between Tomcat and websphere? What i have thought of is - deploy a servlet on Tomcat and make a servlet to servlet connection using java.net.URL & URL connection. Which redirect the request coming on tomcat server from client to Websphere server application and get a response back in terms of byte stream.

what are the pros and cons of using such solution? What are other alternatives or better design options?

Comment: What's the functional requirement? What are both webapps/servlets supposed to do? Why would you for example not just send a redirect to the other webapp? Only then we can suggest the "best" approach.

Comment: application on Websphere generates certain reports based on the parameters passed to it from client via tomcat server. these reports are transfsred back to tomcat server in form of byte stream and converted to PDF files. these PDF files are published on browser based client.

Comment: So essentially, we have two tiers of servers (tomcat & WAS) WAS server is in secured zone behind a firewall and can not be exposed directly to client for security reasons. Application on WAS server is servlet based. I thought of having a servlet on TOmcat to make the connection to WAS, get the response back in bytestream and convert back to PDF. any better approach?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see your second comment while typing the answer. Well, in this case there's no better approach. By the way, what exactly do you mean when you say "convert bytes to PDF"? Do those bytes represent another file format or something? If the other server already returns PDF, you just have to stream it through without converting anything.

Answer (score 0):

You could let the client send the request to the other server directly. So instead of

```
<form action="generatereport" method="post">
```

use

```
<form action="http://other.com/generatereport" method="post">
```

any extra parameters could be passed by `<input type="hidden">`.

---

Or if supports GET, you could instead of `method="get"` also just do

```
<a href="http://other.com/generatereport?param=foo">
```

or

```
response.sendRedirect("http://other.com/generatereport?param=foo");
```

---

Or if there are certain security restrictions and/or the client shouldn't know about the URL of the other server, then your best bet is indeed to play for proxy yourself with help of `URLConnection`.

```
URLConnection connection = new URL("http://other.com/generatereport").openConnection();
// Copy necessary request headers from request.getHeader() to connection.setRequestProperty().
// If POST, copy request.getInputStream() to connection.getOutputStream() as well.
// Copy necessary response headers from connection.getHeaderField() to response.setHeader().
// Finally copy connection.getInputStream() to response.getOutputStream().
```